# How to close colorbox within iframe?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

First off I am new to Javascripting and ColorBox and have been trying for 4 days now to get this to work.  I am sure it is relatively simple, but I just can't seem to get things right.

I have a main page which has a link which open a ColorBox using an IFrame to load a PHP page to allow data input.  I would like the ColorBox to close once the user saves the data.

I found this [how to close colorbox within iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101011/how-to-close-colorbox-within-iframe) but sadly the solution from the last post does not work in my case?!

I use the following in the main page to launch the ColorBox

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".newEntry").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true, onClosed:function(){location.reload();}});
});

The in the PHP page I have tried various things.  I use the $done variable to only close the ColorBox if the data save was successful.

if($done==FALSE){
 echo '
$(document).load(function() {
 parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
 window.close();
 parent.$(".iframe").colorbox.close(); 
});';
}

If someone could show me what to do and, even better, explain a little, it would be greatly appreciated!

Also, on a side note, is there a way to make a ColorBox modal, so the ColorBox remain in focus until it is closed?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Is the echoed JavaScript code inside a <script> tag in the PHP output page?

Comment: Yes

....
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<?php
if($done==TRUE){ 
   echo ' $(document).load(function() { 
      parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); 
      window.close(); 
      parent.$(".iframe").colorbox.close(); 
   });'; 
}
?>
</script>
...

and is locate in the Head section of the HTML.

For instance if I use parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); I get an parent.$.fn is null or not an object, if that helps at all.

Also if I set iframe=False then parent.$.fn.close() works?!

Comment: Are the main and iframe pages both on the same domain?