# colorbox close button with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

I am using colorbox for modal popup and the content of the popup is coming from a URL since this is displayed inside an iFrame how can I add a close button to the modal popup?

Thanks

This is the code for color box

```
<a class="Modal" href="http://google.com" onclick="openModal();">Click here</a>
```

And the js:

```
var openModal = function (){        
     $(".Modal").colorbox({
         iframe:true, 
         opacity:0.5, 
         scrolling:true, 
         width:832, 
         height:456, 
         top:60
     });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to close colorbox within iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101011/how-to-close-colorbox-within-iframe)

Comment: I am really not sure how can I display and anchor link since the iframe is generated by colorbox.

Comment: <a class="Modal" href="http://google.com" onclick="openModal();">Click here 
</a>

var openModal = function (){  
  $(".Modal").colorbox({iframe:true, opacity:0.5, scrolling:true, width:832, height:456, top:60});

}

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this to `colorbox-iframe.html`

```
<input type="button" name="btnClose" value="Close" onclick="parent.$.colorbox.close()" />
```

Comment: but there is no colobox-iframe.html I am re-directing the user to a URL

Comment: I have just given an example as colorbox-iframe.html.In your case your Iframe link and each Iframe has a button that you can use it as closebtn.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used colorbox before, but maybe you want to add the close button via jQuery in your function:

```
var openModal = function (){        
     $(".Modal").colorbox({
         iframe:true, 
         opacity:0.5, 
         scrolling:true, 
         width:832, 
         height:456, 
         top:60
     });

     $("<div class='thisClosesTheModal'>Close Modal</div>").appendTo(".Modal");
     // style .thisClosesTheModal to look like a close box
}

// and then the function that closes the modal

$(".thisClosesTheModal").live('click', function(){

   $('Modal').hide();

}
```