# Calling colorbox close from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox

I'm trying to call colorbox close() function from the iframe. This is what I have.

Main page

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#click").colorbox({width:"60%",
                        height:"60%",
                        iframe:true

            });
        });
    </script>

     <a href="login.html" id="click">Click Me!</a>
```

Login.html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
          <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
    </head><body></body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error when settimeout is called.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

I tried to follow the answer in this thread.
[how to close colorbox within iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101011/how-to-close-colorbox-within-iframe)

Comment: Try removing `.fn` only `parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();`

Comment: 'cannot read property colorbox of undefined'

Comment: Do you ever reference `colorbox` script...?

Comment: @Dom.. yes I do. I manually type the code here, that's why it was missing. Edited the question.  Even then, it is not the issue with colorbox. There is something weird going on with "parent" itself. I have tried looking at what is inside "parent" with Chrome and it was empty. Is there is anyway to print the contents of "parent"? May be that would help identifying the issue.

Answer (score 3):

We can use

> parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();

It works fine